# Group related grunt tasks configuration together

Tags: gruntjs

This is probably a FAQ, but browsing the doc did not help, and I'm giving up.

I have to run a grunt task that involve using several other grunt tasks. Each of those tasks have to be configured differently. Something like this :

```
grunt.initConfig({
  clean : {
      task1 : ["task1"],
      task2 : ["task2"]
  },
  mkdir : {
      task1 : {
          options : {
              create : ["task1"]
          }
      },
      task2 : {
          options : {
              create : ["task2"]
          }
      }
  }
});

...

grunt.registerTask("task1", ["clean:task1", "mkdir:task1"]);
grunt.registerTask("task2", ["clean:task2", "mkdir:task2"]);
```

I can do the job by using :

```
grunt task1
```

This works fine, but I don't understand why the various steps of "task1" have to be scattered all around the config. Besides, if I have many such tasks, my buildfile will become unmaintanable.

So my questions :

- in grunt parlance, what should I call "task1" ? Is it a task ? What should I call "mkdir:task1" ? Is is a subtask ? A task configuration ?
- How should I organise my gruntfile in such a case ? Do I have to create a different npm project for "task1" ? How would this project look (don't hesitate pointing to a guide to writing such tasks for complete grunt noob, I would love to read anything that goes beyond 'Here is my huge and unmaintanable gruntfile to watch files, isn't this great ?)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> in grunt parlance, what should I call "task1" ? Is it a task ? What should I call "mkdir:task1" ? Is is a subtask ? A task configuration ?

What is task1? Are you building views into HTML? Are you concat/minifying scripts? A task name for such things might be `buildviews` or `compress`. There's no real right or wrong way to name your tasks, I'd recommend just being descriptive.

> How should I organise my gruntfile in such a case ? Do I have to create a different npm project for "task1" ? How would this project look (don't hesitate pointing to a guide to writing such tasks for complete grunt noob, I would love to read anything that goes beyond 'Here is my huge and unmaintanable gruntfile to watch files, isn't this great ?)

No, you don't need a different npm project. You seem to be on the right track of defining different configuration options for what you need to do. For example, if you have a `rsync` task, you might have different options for staging and production like I did here:

```
    rsync: {
        staging: {
            files: 'public/',
            options: {
                host: "mystaginghost.com",
                remoteBase: "/page.com/htdocs",
            }
        },
        styles: {
            files: 'public/stylesheets/',
            options: {
                host: "myproductionhost.com",
                remoteBase: "/production.com/htdocs/public/stylesheets/",
            }
        },
    },
```

I'd be able to reference these tasks individually either by calling `grunt rsync:staging` from the command line or setting my task to include `rsync:staging`.

I'd recommend browsing through example Gruntfiles to really understand how to structure yours.

Two good ones are [semantic-ui's](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/blob/master/Gruntfile.js) or the [one from yeoman backbone generator](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-backbone/blob/master/app/templates/Gruntfile.js).

Comment: I meant "what do you call a thing like the thing I called 'task1'". Surely, in real life it would be something like "package" , and it would have several steps, each of which corresponds to a specific configuration of a grunt-task.

Comment: My problem is : if I have ten such "processes", each of which using many different grunt-task configurations, the configurations will be scatered in my Gruntfile, right ? Isn't that terrible for readability / maintenance ?

Comment: For example, with semantic-ui's Gruntfile, suppose I want to understand what "grunt docs" does ; I have to navigate between line 90 (the list of subtask), line 465 (the first use of 'copy'), then line 239 (the use of autoprefix), then 328 (the second use of 'copy'), then 266 (the use of 'docco'), etc... Doesn't sound like fun :(

Comment: Not really sure how to make it much simpler for you. I think it's safe to say that almost any sort of programming, pieces of application logic aren't necessarily in a line for easy consumption. You might want to take a look at Gulp (https://github.com/wearefractal/gulp) if Grunt doesn't seem to have a syntax you like.

Answer (score 0):

If you have many similar task sequences, then you could register a task with a function that takes the arguments you send to it and instead of having 10 tasks you will then have one. This will require your targets to follow a common naming convention though.